# HTML underline button

Tags: javascript, html, css, underline

Hi there I am working on making a word processor, and need to make a button to underline the text in the text area. I have made one button that makes the text italic but unsure on the underline button. Any help would be appreciated

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="myP" >
      Type text here...
</textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set font Italic</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontStyle = "italic";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">underline</button>

<script>
function myFunction2() {
document.getElementById("myP").style.textDecoration = "underline";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `textDecoration` property from the style object which, in turn, will modify the [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) CSS style:

```
function underline_text(){
    document.getElementById("myP").style.textDecoration = "underline";
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpwuy0qy/1/)